# How many points uniquely identify a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

The [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is uniquely identified by its mean and variance.  I am interested in how many distinct values of the [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) are needed to uniquely determine the mean and variance.

Is this well known?

My guess is that maybe <strike>2</strike> 3 points is all that is needed.

- If we are given two points to the left of the peak, it looks like this is enough. If we have 3 points then at least two must be on one side of the peak (unless one is actually at the peak).
- It seems two normal distributions can intersect at at most 2 points. A third point might then be sufficient to uniquely identify the distribution.

Comment: What do you think? People are more likely to answer your question if they can see you have put some effort into answering the question yourself first

Comment: @lioness99a I am just guessing but I added my guess nonetheless.

Comment: Why do you think that $2$ is all that is necessary?

Comment: @lioness99a I really have no idea.. but more guesswork added :)

Comment: In your link you have pictures of normal distribution graphs that intersect twice. So in general, two points will not always be enough.

Comment: @paw88789 That's a good point. So it looks like we are looking for a proof that three points is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like typically (always?) you will need three points to distinguish a specific normal curve.  Let's look at the case of one curve being standard normal, and the other being general:

To find intersection points, we need to solve:

$$e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sigma}\cdot e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

This can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{\sigma}=e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

Upon taking logarithms, you will generally get a quadratic in $x$, so two solutions (usually).

This means that most normal curves will intersect twice, thus requiring $3$ points for unique determination.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, two points are usually enough.  Each one gives you one equation that involves the mean and variance.  You need two equations to evaluate two unknowns.  You may need a third to resolve ambiguity.  Most likely this will have to be a numeric evaluation.

Comment: Please see my comment above.

Comment: @paw88789:  Good point.  I have updated.

Comment: "You need two equations to evaluate two unknowns." may be a good heuristic, but is far from true for general non-linear equations. Can you provide evidence that you do not always need 3 points here?

Comment: @Klaus:  two distributions with the same variance and different means will only cross once, so two points would suffice. I believe if you get the peak and one other point you will have only one solution as well

Comment: @RossMillikan But how many points do you need to fix the variance, or the peak?

Comment: If you know it is the peak one point will certainly fix the variance as in a z-score table.  In fact, if you are told it is the peak one point is all you need because you have the mean and the value gives the variance-low value means high variance.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, but that hardly addresses the question, does it? See paw's answer.