# How many points uniquely determine a skew normal distribution?

Tags: calculus, statistics, normal-distribution

The [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) pdf is defined to be:

$$
\phi(x| \mu, \sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^2}}
$$

The cdf is given by:

$$
\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \phi(t) dt
$$

If we are given the value of $\phi(x)$ at three distinct points, this is [sufficient to uniquely determine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558479/how-many-points-uniquely-identify-a-normal-distribution) $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

The pdf of the general [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) is defined to be:

$$
f(x)=\frac{2}{\omega} \phi\left(\frac{x-\xi}{\omega}\right) \Phi\left(\alpha\left(\frac{x-\xi}{\omega}\right)\right)
$$

> How many points are needed to determine $\xi$, $\omega$ and $\alpha$?

Even though we have one more variable than in the non-skewed case, <strike>it looks like two skew normal distributions can only intersect in two places. So maybe we need only three again?</strike>

---

@Rahul points out in the comments that the pdf of two skew normal distributions can in fact  intersect at three points. This leads to the guess, is four points sufficient to uniquely determine the distribution?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The PDF of the skew normal distribution with $\xi=-1.5,\omega=2,\alpha=5$ intersects the PDF of the standard normal distribution ($\xi=0,\omega=1,\alpha=0$) in three places.

Comment: @Rahul That's very interesting! So my initial guess is wrong. Do you think we need 4 points?

Comment: Clearly we need at least 4. Beyond that I have no idea.

Comment: @Rahul If the maximum number of intersection points is 3 then this seems to imply 4 is sufficient, right? If so, the problem is establishing that claim. Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: a better way to ask might be how many samples are needed such that one can differentiate a skew normal distribution from a mere 2-parameter normal distribution ... for instance if I randomly draw 4 samples from a normal distribution, one can obtain 3 best-fit parameters for a skew normal distribution, but does not prove that the underlying population distribution was/is in fact skew normal

Comment: @phdmba7of12 Isn’t the skew normal a generalisation of the 2-parameter normal?  If so, I am not sure your comment makes sense.

Comment: @Anush my point was directed more towards figures of merit for statistical distribution regression goodness which take into account not only the degree to which a distribution fits a sample, but the number of parameters in that distribution ... thinking AICc, BIC and -2Loglikelihood

Comment: @phdmba7of12 Got you. But in this case the OP is just asking a pure mathematical question about the number of equations you need to have a unique solution. I am surprised no one has answered yet to be honest.